# TF-IDF Vectors Example (HELP)

Tags: python, tensorflow, vector, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

Hey i made 3 different approaches but i can't decide which is the right way to use TF-IDF:

The first code does fit and transform to both x_train and x_test separately giving (5000, 94462)
(5000, 93007).

The second code uses both train and test which i think is not right because idf is calculated based on the training documents only, giving (5000, 152800) (5000, 152800).

The third code gives (5000, 94462) (5000, 94462).

### For me the third code is right because i used train data only and transform test data based on them.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
xtrain_tfidf = vectorizer.fit_transform(x_train)
xtest_tfidf = vectorizer.fit_transform(x_test)
print(xtrain_tfidf.shape)
print(xtest_tfidf.shape)
```

---

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
vectorizer.fit(x_train+x_test)
xtrain_tfidf = vectorizer.transform(x_train)
xtest_tfidf = vectorizer.transform(x_test)
print(xtrain_tfidf.shape)
print(xtest_tfidf.shape)
```

---

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
vect = TfidfVectorizer()
vect.fit(x_train)
x_test_vectorized = vect.transform(x_test)
```

---

Comment: what is the third? you mentioned 3 but specified only 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way is to `fit` and `transform` == `fit_transform` your training data and **only** `transform` test data.

```py
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
xtrain_tfidf = vectorizer.fit_transform(x_train)
xtest_tfidf = vectorizer.transform(x_test)
print(xtrain_tfidf.shape)
print(xtest_tfidf.shape)
```

You **never** `fit_transform` test data.